# How is the time complexity of deletion N steps aka O(n)?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm starting to teach myself data structures and algorithms and currently am learning time complexity of an array.

From the book I am learning from, it states that Searching an array takes N steps since worst-case scenario would be that you have to search each and every cell for the data element.

Then why is Deletion from an array also N steps?

From my understanding, a computer allocates memory for an array and takes note of the beginning of the array via a memory address. For deletion, wouldn't you still have to search each index of that array for the data element you want to delete, delete that data element, then shift the remaining data elements?

Maybe I'm still too early into this chapter but I'm pretty confused as to how deletion itself only takes 1 step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an array of size `N` and your element to delete is at position `M` with `M < N`,
then you need `M` steps to find the element and afterwards need to shift `N-M` elements, thus `O(M + (N-M)) = O(N)`

Comment: Ok that makes perfect sense, I think I'm still too early into this chapter. In the end it's linear which I understand. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem assumes that the node to be deleted is known and a pointer to that node is available.

In order to delete a node and connect the previous and the next node together, you need to know their pointers. In a doubly-linked list, both pointers are available in the node that is to be deleted. The time complexity is constant in this case, i.e., O(1).

Whereas in a singly-linked list, the pointer to the previous node is unknown and can be found only by traversing the list from head until it reaches the node that has a next node pointer to the node that is to be deleted. The time complexity in this case is O(n).
Actually deletion in singly linked lists can also be implemented in O(1).

Given a singly linked list with the following state:

```
SinglyLinkedList:
   Node 1 -> Node 2
   Node 2 -> Node 3
   Node 3 -> Node 4
   Node 4 -> None

   Head = Node 1
```

Insertion and deletion at a known position is O(1). However, finding that position is O(n), unless it is the head or tail of the list.

When we talk about insertion and deletion complexity, we generally assume we already know where that's going to occur.

In cases where the node to be deleted is known only by value, the list has to be searched and the time complexity becomes O(n) in both singly- and doubly-linked lists.

I think this gives an a view on the topic

Answer (score 1):

Lets you want to delete m from an array of size n.
Its depends on the array is sorted or not.
Take everything in the worst case.
If the array is sorted worst-case time complexity to search m in the array is log(n)
let's number m found at first index(0) then you need to shift array left from index 1 to n-1.
Time complexity to shift is O(n) approx and O(log(n))+O(n)= O(n)
If the array is not sorted worst-case time complexity to search m in the array is O(n) in the.
And need to shift left and it will take O(n)+O(n)= O(n)